# What is a good way of guarding against NPEs while recalling attributes of objects in lists?

Tags: apex

An as example, say I have a trigger (list object) with accounts in it, and I want to compare the "Status" attribute of an account to a String. This is how I do it right now:

```
if (trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c != null && trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c.contains('active')) {}
```

My true purpose is simply to execute the second expression, but in the case that the current account did not have a Status, I would be returned a NPE because of the compareTo call. So I add in a not null check first which seems like a terribly inefficient way of doing things.

How can this be done better?

Comment: Terribly inefficient way of doing things?  Certainly not in terms of performance.  In terms of code length you could clean this up by storing `Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id)` in a variable.

Comment: It doesn't gain any efficiency, but you could check out the [apex-lang commons](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/), specifically the [StringUtils](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/source/browse/tags/1.18/src/classes/StringUtils.cls). If you find yourself implementing the same types of private utility functions for null check and then do x, something like this (or your own) that unifies/centralizes functionality might help you not repeat yourself...of course it is another dependency...

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have, but my personal preference would be to use a ternary (or nested-ternary if necessary): `if (trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c == null ? false : trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c.contains('active')) {}` Its actually slightly longer in this case, but I think can be cleaner for more complex evaluations. Agree with @phil-r - you are more likely to be using a variable, in which case you might have: `if (oldItem.Status__c == null ? false : oldItem.Status__c.contains('active')) {}`

Answer (score 3):

You could use isNotBlank or isNotEmpty instead (though I guess it amounts to the same as a null check)

```
if ( String.isNotBlank(trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c) &&  trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c.contains('active') ) {}
```

> According to the docs, isNotBlank Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.

To code defensively you will have to do some kind of check, whether it be null checking or isBlank/isEmpty etc. if there is a chance that Status__c could be null.

What you could do is write your own static method to check and return '' if null? e.g.

```
static String makeNullString( String in ) {
  return in == null ? '' : in;
}
```

Then you could do this instead:

```
if (makeNullString(trigger.oldMap.get(account.id).Status__c).contains('active')) {}
```

Comment: compareTo was just an example, I have to use .contains() in most cases; using contains in an example would require more context, so I just used a generic string method.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense I couldn't work out what you were trying to do. I guess there are variations on a theme of how to do it, but I don't think you will get away from having to do something. Updated answer slightly.